# How To Run A Shell Script Again And Again Having X Interval Of Time In Root?

Tags: boot, 14.04, root, cron, scripts

I have a shell script in my **Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS** at `./ShellScript.sh`. I setup `/etc/rc.local` to run the shell script after boot but before login using below code.

To run run it boot write this command in terminal: `sudo nano /etc/rc.local` then add following and save.

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

#!/bin/bash

./ShellScript.sh

exit 0
```

Note: Keep in mind that I am working in `root` mode. Now when I run `crontab -e` then I got the following. Now What to do?

```
no crontab for root - using an empty one
Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
1. /bin/ed
2. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
3. /usr/bin/vim.basic
4. /usr/bin/vim.tiny
Choose 1-4 [2]:
```

After selecting `2`, I got `crontab: "/usr/bin/sensible-editor" exited with status 2`

Now I want to run/execute this shell script again and again having 15min of time interval between every run after boot but before login. So Can I do it?

### Answer:

First of all, you can't access `crontab -e` via root. You have to login via USER account. After login in USER account, Go to terminal and type `crontab -e` Here you will get some text like below.

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
```

Now I=in the end of file, you have to add `*/15 * * * * /ShellScript.sh` line to run your script each after 15 min. Now save the file and its done.

**Note:**
If you want different timing of interval to run script again and again then don't get confused. Here are some online tools that will generate Cron lines for you.

1. http://www.cronmaker.com/
2. http://crontab-generator.org/
3. http://www.generateit.net/cron-job/
4. http://cron.nmonitoring.com/cron-generator.html
5. http://www.openjs.com/scripts/jslibrary/demos/crontab.php

Comment: Yes, and you can press enter at that prompt, since you are familiar with `nano`.

Comment: Uh, select 2, which is `nano`.

Comment: Try this: `export EDITOR=/usr/bin/nano; crontab -e`. Also, you can use your own `crontab` instead of root's.

Comment: Not `./ShellScript.sh`, but the full path.

Comment: It is better to use the full, absolute path (one starting with `/`, like `/etc/rc.local`), when calling a script from another one (unless you are sure you control your current dir totally). If you're unsure, you can use `readlink -f ./ShellScript.sh` to have the absolute path.

Comment: */15 will run it **every** 15mn, this is not the same as to start 15mn after the last run has finished.

Comment: Downvoted because I think the OP is just asking us to solve his problem rather than wanting to learn the solution. Also this question has been solved in the duplicate.

Comment: Can you explain in what why this is different from a normal cron job?

Comment: First: you should not edit your question to contain the answer; second: the downvote was to motivate you to explain (by editing) why your question was different. It would be reverted on the edit. That said, you are right: they are only internet points. Third, it is absolutely permissable to ask a pseudo-duplicate question *if* you can prove why it is different. Anyway, best of luck.

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't you simply run it in the background, inside a while loop:

```
while true
 do
    [command]
    sleep [number of seconds]
 done
```

So the construction would be:

- Add a line in `/etc/rc.local` to call your script (your `ShellScript.sh`) + "&" to make it exit
- Run the commands you want the `ShellScript.sh` to execute in a while loop (inside `Shellscript.sh`):

  ```
  while true
   do
      [command_1]
      [command_2]
      [command_3]
      [command_4]
      sleep 900
   done
  ```

That way it would run on startup and from then on every 15 minutes

Note that if you want to run it from `cron`, you need to set the full path, since `cron` runs with a limited set of environment variables.

**Example:**

I created a silly script, adding a line with the string "monkey" to a file `test.txt` on my desktop:

*the script*:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
 do
    echo monkey>>/home/jacob/Desktop/test.txt
    sleep 5
 done
```

The line in my `/etc/rc.local` file:

```
sh /home/jacob/Desktop/while.sh &
```

That's all.

Comment: @MuhammadHassan I believe this is what he meant, with 900 seconds, not 15 ;) Then just call your script in the background, i.e. `./Shellscript.sh &`